# Pjax not degrading properly on IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, pjax

I'm passing the following url with parameters following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937530/is-there-any-way-to-programmatically-call-and-execute-pjax-from-within-my-javasc) to programatically call pjax.

```js
var url = '/activity?fromDate='+$('#from-date').val()+'&toDate='+$('#to-date').val();
$.pjax({url: url, container: '#main-body'});
```

This works perfectly fine on modern browsers, but fails to include any parameters on Internet Explorer 9 and below.  The page just navigates to `/activity`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 9 [does not support pushState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722815/does-internet-explorer-support-pushstate-and-replacestate) which pjax relies on to work.  When the pushState API is unavailable, `$.pjax` calls the [`fallbackPjax()`](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/jquery.pjax.js#L501) function.

The fallback creates a hidden `<form>` and puts the `url` you specified in the action field of the form.  **Any parameters in the action field of the form are ignored.**

There are two things that need to be done.

```js
var url = '/activity';
var data = 'fromDate='+$('#from-date').val()+'&toDate='+$('#to-date').val();
$.pjax({url: url, data: data, container: '#main-body', method: 'GET' });
```

1. You need to specify the `method` as GET (which the fallback will default as a POST)
2. You need pass your parameters in the `data` field of options.

The fallback automatically loops through your parameters and creates input fields for each one.